Recurring movement of complete files
I would like to address a query that may have been previously discussed or addressed indirectly through other inquiries.
I am in need of a solution for recurrently moving files with a specific file extension from one folder to another. However, due to the automated extraction process, it is imperative that the script can identify and skip files that are not completely extracted.
I have already devised a preliminary script and tested it with crontab. Now, I seek to enhance it by incorporating the following functionalities:

Specifying the handling of files with a specific extension
Implementing a mechanism to skip files that are incompletely extracted

Best
Luca

After the first reply, I made this script.
The file before extraction are .rar (also divided in .part), but with this script I almost resolved everything
#!/bin/bash

# Source folder
source_folder="-----"

# Destination folder
destination_folder="-----"

# File extension to be moved file_extension="-----"

# Iteration through the files with the specified extension
for file in "$source_folder"/*"$file_extension"; do
    # Check if the file is open
    if ! lsof "$file" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        # move the file
        mv "$file" "$destination_folder"
    fi
done


Please [edit] your question and show us the script, explain what kind of compression and/or archiving you are using, how you can have the same extensions for a compressed and uncompressed file and just generally give us a lot more detail so we can understand what you need and help you.

You can use a utility such as fuser or lsof to find whether a process is writing to the file. This is only useful if the files are extracted by a process on the same host, and if that process continuously has the file open for writing.
What to do if the extraction process fails or aborts (e.g. due to a system reboot)? What do you want to do with an incompletely extracted file that isn't actively being extracted?
Can you recognize the end of a completely extracted file? If you can, then I would use that as your criterion. Depending on the file format, I'd use awk, perl or python to detect the end of file. (If it's in a structured format, such as JSON, you want to use a library to parse it; such libraries are readily available for Perl and Python.)
Once you have a script, say, is-complete, that decides whether a file is complete or not (by returning exit code 0 for success and any other number for failure), you can move the files in a single command:
find extraction-directory -type f -name '*.desiredext' -exec is-complete {} \; -exec mv -t final-directory/ {} \;


Hi @Reinier lsof seems working.
This is the script that I wrote. I am not interest at the moment on checking incomplete file.
Super thanks
`#!/bin/bash
Source folder
source_folder="-----"
Destination folder
destination_folder="-----"
File extension to be moved
file_extension="-----"
Iteration through the files with the specified extension
for file in "$source_folder"/*"$file_extension"; do
# Check if the file is open
if ! lsof "$file" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
# move the file
mv "$file" "$destination_folder"
    fi
done`

@LucaPanareo please add the script to your question, not as a comment. And note that unless you run this as root, lsof will only report your processes accessing the file.

done, I think lsof is fine because the extraction process is done by the same user of the script
